# how to calculate capacity of the ddr address line

Tags: ddr

i see the micron data sheet 8-GB,4-GB and 1-GB the address lines are 16,15,13 
my question is how to calculate the capacity of the (double data rate type three synchronous dynamic random-access memory )  by address lines

Comment: DDRx memories are not like SRAM or Flash where address lines will address complete memory. Because DDRx offers huge storage for same die like SRAM or FLASH, they split the total address in to ROW and COLUMN addresses so, that Total address lines required will be ~ LogTotal addressing base 2 /2..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot figure out the SDRAM capacity by simply looking at the number of address lines. The address lines are time multiplexed to convey a Row address and a Column address. The Row and Column addresses are not necessarily the same width. For example, given 16 physical address lines, all 16 may be valid for Row address while only 12 valid for Column address. That would give a combined address of 28 bits. Furthermore, there can be a bank address. For example, adding a 3-bit bank address would make that into 31 bits. Now, 2^31 would address 2G words of memory. To express the memory density in GB(yte), further multiply with word width and divide by 8.